# How to find elements of vector which correspond to range?

Tags: r, vector, range

I have a problem with my code in R. I just began to study this program. I have to count the average value for the numbers in the vector that fit within the range between the maximum and minimum.
I wrote a code and the result is not correct, I have the impression the range doesn't work.

```
x.sd <- function(x) {
  x.sd <- sqrt(var(x))
}
x.min <- function (x) {
  x.min <- x.m(x) - 2 * x.sd(x)
}
x.max <- function(x){
  x.max <- x.m(x) + 2 * x.sd(x)
}
res <- 0
i <- res + 1
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  x_i <- function(x){
  x_i <- c(c(x.min(x) <= x) & c(x <= x.max(x)))
  i_x <- which(x_i == TRUE)
  }
  x_m <- function(x){
    x_m <- x[i_x] 
    return(x_m)
x.m2 <- function(x_m){
  x.m2 <- sum(x_m)/length(x_m)
```

Could you please help me to fix this problem or give me some advice on which function I can use?

Comment: Please show a [reproducible minimal dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), an expected output and the error.

Comment: dataset: my_vec <- c(10, 52, 52, 41, 35, 45, 42, 45, 52, 41, 52, 50, 0)
Expected output: 43.08333
And the result is 39.76923
It looks like the formula doesn’t work inside and counts the whole vector

Comment: The idea is finding all the meanings which are in the range x.min() and x.max() and then count the average meaning from this numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time following your code, but are you looking for something like this?

```
x <- c(10, 52, 52, 41, 35, 45, 42, 45, 52, 41, 52, 50, 0)
mean(x[abs(x - mean(x)) < 2*sd(x)])
#> [1] 43.08333
```

This matches the expected output mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Yes, but it gives the same result is mine. And I need to make an extraction from the first vector.

Comment: See the updated answer that matches the expected output mentioned in the comments.